# the second condition in the if statment with or operator

Tags: java

I have the following if statment which contains of two conditions with or perator. So in the following code I am getting this error
`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`
I thought in java the second condition in the if statment is checked if the first condition is not valid.

The compressDuration could be empty or null or blank or a String vlaue like 100.

In the case below the compressDuration is empty also it is blank also the second condition `Integer.parseInt(compressDuration.trim())` must not be checked?

How can I write the if statment to conver the 4 cases `empty or null or blank or a String vlaue like 100.`?

```
String compressDuration = "";
   if(StringUtils.isBlank(compressDuration) || Integer.parseInt(compressDuration.trim())){
    System.out.println("The compressDuration  has no value or a ");

   }else{

    }
```

Comment: Have your tried debugging this?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't pass compilation. You can't pass an `int` as an operand of binary OR. Perhaps you are running an earlier version of the code that did pass compilation and throws the exception you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought in java the second condition in the if statment is checked if the first condition is not valid.

I assume you mean **not** checked if the first condition is false. And that's correct, it isn't. So clearly, `StringUtils.isBlank` isn't returning `false` for `""` ***if*** what's in your question is a valid example of what you're doing.

I suspect, though, that you have a string with whitespace in it, not `""`. Note that you're using `trim` when passing to `Integer.parseInt`, but **not** when passing to `StringUtils.isBlank`.

Note that as [Eran pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152207/the-second-condition-in-the-if-statment-with-or-operator/44152244#comment75321475_44152207), your code doesn't compile; `int` can't be used with the `||` operator, but your code has the condition `boolean || int`, which lends weight to the idea that this code isn't an accurate representation of what you actually have.

But I suspect it's the `trim` in the one case but not the other which is the problem.

Perhaps:

```
String compressDuration = /*...get it from wherever...*/;
compressDuration = compressDuration.trim();
int duration;
if (StringUtils.isBlank(compressDuration) || (duration = Integer.parseInt(compressDuration.trim())) < 0) {
    System.out.println("The compressDuration  has no value or a value less than zero");
} else {
    System.out.println("The compressDuration  is " + duration);
}
```

or if you don't like side-effects in `if` conditions (and there are good reasons to not like them, but I make some exceptions for very simple cases):

```
String compressDuration = /*...get it from wherever...*/;
compressDuration = compressDuration.trim();
int duration = StringUtils.isBlank(compressDuration) ? -1 : Integer.parseInt(compressDuration.trim();
if (duration < 0) {
    System.out.println("The compressDuration  has no value or a value less than zero");
} else {
    System.out.println("The compressDuration  is " + duration);
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right not checked! is there a way to do the check in one if statment for the for cases? I am wirting the code in the groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

Try `isInt` method which will return true if it is valid integer.

```
if(!isInt(compressDuration.trim())) {
   System.out.println("The compressDuration  has no value or a ");
} else{

}

public boolean isInt(String str) {

  try{
   int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
   // is an integer!
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   // not an integer!
   return false;
 }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: *"@ tree, Please see this answer"* The person posting the question is notified of every answer posted, there's no need to @-ping them.